# Is there a means to measure pH without indicators?

Tags: home-experiment, ph, experimental-chemistry

I have created a solution that should contain hydroxide ions. Therefore, the pH > 7, but is there any way to roughly estimate the pH in absence of any indicator? Maybe using current, or checking whether it dissolves certain chemicals?

Please mind that I am limited in equipment and so complex science is not feasible for me.

Comment: You could make your own [red cabbage indicator](http://chemistry.about.com/od/acidsbase1/a/red-cabbage-ph-indicator.htm)

Comment: I cannot make that,... I am not allowed to by the household ;p so in that respect I am restricted

Comment: Basic solutions are slippery (like soap).

Comment: How accurate do you need to be, and what kinds of materials are realistically available to you? Is there any particular reason why you can't purchase some inexpensive litmus paper or a universal indicator? If you expect the solution to be highly basic, then you may be able to get a very rough qualitative sense of its basicity by reacting it with an acid and measuring temperature change. Another possibility is reacting it with soluble salts of common metals (e.g., calcium or magnesium) and looking for a precipitate of the insoluble hydroxide. Use a control sample of plain water for comparison.

Comment: precipitation reactions are possible, ill take a look at that. Any suggestions of certain salts that are readily available?

Comment: Calcium chloride is the first one that comes to mind, since it's readily available for purchase and highly soluble, while the hydroxide is orders of magnitude less soluble.

Comment: If the household don't allow you to use red cabbage indicator I really don't know what else more easy and safety to do you can use :-)

Comment: Another possibility that comes to mind is zinc oxide. This can be purchased in bulk, and while it dissolves in both acidic and basic solutions (it is an amphoteric compound), it is very insoluble in neutral ones.

Comment: Zinc oxide sounds promising

Comment: I decided to check whether it dissolved organic materials like small leaves or so.. than I know that it is very strong. I also have acid that I can mix in miser quantities to check heat formation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried with red or black tea? It turns lighter in acidic media and turns dark in basic media. I tried once adding the pulp juice of one lemon to a cup of tea and it lighted up (mainly for acetic acid), then I added NaOH-based salt and turned very black and opaque.

Maybe that suits for your solution.

Comment: The ideal solution for me! Thank you! Maybe you have a chemical explanation? That would be very nice.

Comment: Good and not a simple question, I believe oxidation - reduction of polyphenols play that role. You can look at this for approach: [www.worldoftea.org](http://www.worldoftea.org/tea-chemistry/)

Comment: I just tested it with earl grey and [it works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mR34M.jpg)!