# Home-made way to detect lye in solution

Tags: home-experiment, analytical-chemistry, solutions

I believe that electrolysis of salt water creates lye ($\ce{NaOH}$ - sodium hydroxide). In salt water, there's $\ce{Na+}$, $\ce{Cl-}$, $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ as of ionts.

So at cathode, you get $\ce{Na2}$ and that should react with water into $\ce{NaOH}$.

I want to test, if this is true - how do I do it with household items? The solution didn't react with aluminium.

Comment: I found more general question asking about [measuring pH using household items](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14314/1677).

Comment: The aluminium probably did not react because of its highly shielding oxide layer.

Comment: I scratched it. I think the solution is not concentrated at all. I've left a drop on my skin and nothing happened.

Comment: A will filter out the copper chloride and procceed with electrolysis.

Comment: Where did you make copper chloride now? This is starting to confuse me...

Comment: I used (intentionally) a copper anode. Copper reacts with chloride. First it forms yellow stuff that dissolves in water. Later on, I can see [orange chunks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc0kn.jpg) that do not dissolve. I didn't talk about this in the original question because it doesn't seem to be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to measure the pH of a solution is to use an acid-base indicator. Limited to household supplies only, I would suggest a solution made from [red cabbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_cabbage), which should turn blue-greenish in the alkaline region.

The ions you actually get from your reaction is a higher concentration of $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$, due to the fact that you are removing $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ (from $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions respectively) via the performed electrolysis. Under no circumstances would you generate a $\ce{Na2}$ species, you would rather write it as $\ce{2Na}$. Also, in aqueous solutions the $\ce{NaOH}$ most certainly dissociates. So speaking of the formation of solid $\ce{NaOH}$ from $\ce{Na}$ in water is quite a stretch.

Bottom line: **Since the salt is already dissolved when you start the electrolysis, all you get is a change in concentration of the ions involved. The thereby induced change in pH can be <s>measured</s> observed using an acid-base indicator such as the juice of the red cabbage.**

Comment: So what happens to $\ce{Na+}$ ionts when I dry the water? I don't think I'm gonna get pure sodium...

Comment: If you evaporate all the water, you will be left with a mixture of NaCl and NaOH. They need water to exist in their ionic form.

Comment: How does the sodium come in contact with chlor? I never meant to think that solid NaOH will appear in water by the way. But since that's what I get after drying the water, it's just about the same.

Comment: Electrostatic interactions. And it comes in contact with chloride, not chlorine. (Chloride is the anion of chlorine.)

Comment: It is easy and cheap to buy pH testing strips from an aquarium store or from Amazon.  I bought [SEOH brand strips from Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001T77WW2/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and have been happy with them.  I'm sure many others are just as good.